# TRIGGER SQL server (see if a hotelroom is already booked)

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to make a trigger for hotel as a exercise, where the number of guests can't be higher then the number of beds in a room. So far I've done triggers that for example makes a room not available for booking of it's already booked the certain date you're trying to book it on (if you do not have the same bookingnumber that is, because of course more than one can live in the room,) That one was quite easier since all important information was in the same table. Here it is split over 3 different table.

Anyhow, I have no idea where to start on this one.

I've got 3 tables.

Size (SizeID, Size, numberofBeds)

Room (Roomnr,price,SizeID)

Guestbooking (bookingnumber, Roomnr, guestnr, arrival, departure.

Is a trigger the right way to go, or should i try to expand my trigger that checked if a room was available for booking?

First time asking here, hope someone understands.

Cheers.

Comment: My first trigger is like this ((arrival >= @ newarrival AND departure <= @ newdeparture) OR
(arrival<= @ newarrival AND departure >= @ newarrival) OR
(arrival <= @ newdeparture AND departure >= @ newdeparture)) AND
Guestbooking.bookingnr <> @ newbookingnr)

This works so i can't book a room that already have the date booked with exception that if the bookingnumber is the same i can put more than 1 people there.

so i tried to fix it with size=>numberofGuests and stuff like that, but it wont allow it since they are on another table compared to Guestbooking for example

Comment: It is not your triggers job to check if a room was booked, you should make a procedure that checks data and updates your tables. If you are still worried about conflicting data, you should make a check constraint to prevent this from happening

Comment: Why can't two people sleep in the same bed?   I don't want to stay at your hotel.

Comment: The thing is there is probably alot easier ways to fix it, but the exercise is to use triggers of some sort unfortunately. The trigger above makes sure that the room doesn't get doublebooked (it was just a short cutout of the whole trigger) The thing now is with a trigger to make sure that if a room has 4 bed, no more than 4 guests can be booked into the room.

Comment: IF NOT (@amountofguests < @amountofbeds) 
BEGIN
 RAISERROR ('Room is already fully booked of people.', 16, 1)
 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
works except that if a room has been booked before then it says to many people live in that room. So im trying to adjust with having a COUNT with amountofbeds >=amountofguests but nothing so far works. Any ideas?